# Grid column renderer tooltip using meta.tdAttr

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, rally, grid-layout

I have been trying to add a tooltip that pops up when you hover over a cell in an Ext.grid.Panel.

However, the parameter "meta" to the renderer function for a column does not have the tdAttr property!

```
renderer : function(value, meta, record, row, col) {
    if (value == 1 && record.data.state === 'Accepted') {
        meta.tdCls = 'green';
        console.log('value',value);
        console.log('meta',meta);
        console.log('meta.tdAttr',meta.tdAttr);
        console.log('meta.style',meta.style);
        meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
        return record.data.id;
    } else if (value == 1 && record.data.state === 'Initial Version') {
        meta.tdCls = 'white';
        return record.data.id;
    } else if (value == 1) {
        meta.tdCls = 'red';
        return record.data.id;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

sample console output:

```
value 1 
meta Object {tdCls: "", style: ""} 
meta.tdAttr undefined 
meta.style
```

I feel like I might be missing some setting on the grid view or the grid panel, but for that property to not even be available on the meta parameter seems strange.  From the documentation:

metaData : Object
A collection of metadata about the current cell; can be used or modified by the renderer. Recognized properties are: tdCls, tdAttr, and style.

Comment: What version of Ext JS are you on?

Comment: We're on the same exact version, and the code `meta.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';` works just fine. Can you replicate the issue on JS fiddle or anything?

Comment: The only thing that could possibly be different is that I am using extjs in the context of developing Rally applications, and rally has built on top of ext js 4.  However, I am using native ext js 4 components, so I see no reason for them not to work in this situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why that setting was not there to begin with, but I added it manually to get around that problem:

```
meta['tdAttr'] = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
```

and it worked!

Comment: This is an HTML Injection risk if you cannot trust value. (I've just found this in code review and sent the developer a screen shot of his application showing the alert "You've been hacked")

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with dynamically show cell tooltip in action column, should help.

```
        {
            xtype: 'actioncolumn',
            name: 'payment',
            width: 70,
            align: 'center',
            dataIndex: 'uid',
            menuDisabled: 'true',
            text: 'xxx',
            sortable: false,
            fixed: 'true',
            renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
                if (value == '0') {
                    metadata.tdCls = 'pay-icon';
                }
                else {
                    metadata.tdCls = 'paid-icon'
                }
            },
            getTip: function (value, metadata, record) {
                if (value == '0') {
                    return 'for pay';
                } else {
                    return 'paid';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Action columns are not really meant to be used this way - and I wanted it to work on hover, which this does not really accomplish.